# how to configuration laravel web when url must open on domain.com/yyy

Tags: php, laravel, indexing, permissions, config

my laravel app will be open in domain domain.or/yyy (requirement from client)
when i upload and run my project on the server, only the landing page work, other page and css error and can't load because their redirect to domain.com instead of domain.com/yyy
example: when i view:page source all css link domain.or/css, so i guess this the problem why css can't load. and all route also give me 403, but when i add /yyy/route, the route run

how to configuration all url,route to redirect to domain.or/yyy

my .httaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        Options +Indexes 
# or #
IndexIgnore *
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st option :** Redirecting all URLs from .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

in your case, it will be

`domain.com/yyy` instead of `example.com`

please check this [Link](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-) it will be very helpful

**2nd option :**
redirect using routes\web.php file as follow:

```
Route::redirect("formExample1.com","toExample2.com");
```

and in 2 above options you may have to review :

1. public\index.php file you may need changes according to CSS, js path.
2. .env file, you may need to modify `APP_URL` value.
3. also ensure you gave the right permission to public\index.php file (755 typical value).

Comment: hi, so i add Redirect 301 / example.com/yyy right? but the page isnt working, already clear cache etc

Comment: you can redirect from route file using redirect ,i'll update my answer

Comment: where is the route.php location? i  cant find it, or u mean routes/web.php?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some configurations.

First, all files and folder cut from in your `public` folder to `yyy`project folder.

Second, in your `index.php` file open and change like below.

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now you have to change `js` and `css` location in your blade file

Hope it is helpful for you